# How to resize the table for a mobile screen size in css?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a table which I want to resize fit to the screen size(mobile view) with the borders visible around the corners. The pictorial representation of the table in the desktop view is:

[image]

The class belonging to the selected part as shown in the above image is:

> class="section single"

The CSS(Desktop View) belonging to the selected part is:

```
.section.single {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.section {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    display: table;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.section {
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #aecaea;
    border-right: 1px solid #aecaea;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aecaea;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC !important;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

The CSS media queries which I have used for resizing the above table is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 320px) {
  .section.single {
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
  }

  .section {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    display: table;
    }
}
```

I am able to resize the table by using the above media queries but unfortunately I am not able to see the borders on the right side of the table after resize.

Comment: @media needs curly braces **{ }** too: `@media screen ... {  .section { }  }`

Comment: My mistake. In the main code, I have used curly braces.

Comment: Please post a working code example (css+html) so your problem can be reproduced...